# Android listview contains buttons that shouldn't be there

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an issue with my `ListView` where for some unknown reason each element has a button that shouldn't have. How could i go about removing these buttons?

[Android emulator showing the buttons in the listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fZNZ.png)

The issue seems to be with my `onPostExecute` method for an async task.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String pResult) {
    //Populate the list view?
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.DownloadablePuzzlesList);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), 
            R.layout.activity_download, R.id.DownloadablePuzzlesText, PuzzleNames);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

After hours of trying to figure this issue out i'm unable to find the solution to my  issue any help would be appreciated.

Comment: give the code snippet of R.layout.activity_download

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `R.layout.activity_download` must be having button.

**Instead of:**

`ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_download, R.id.DownloadablePuzzlesText, PuzzleNames);`

**Do:**

`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, PuzzleNames)`

Comment: I changed the code what what you said and was given a constructor error, changing to: `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DownloadPuzzleActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, PuzzleNames);` Has fixed the issue for me, Thank you.